# question about the automatic coercion in java?

Tags: java

Many people have recommended me to read the book "Java - the Complete reference". I started reading it actually and I found this text:

> "**There are no automatic coercions or conversions of conflicting types
>   as in some languages**. The Java compiler checks all expressions and
>   parameters to ensure that the types are compatible. Any type
>   mismatches are errors that must be corrected before the"

doesn't this contradict with the :
System.out.println("string"+ a);

where `a` is any primitive type. Isn't that an implicit type conversion which is an automatic coercion.

As an example, string and integer are not compatible types.

Note: I am not a native english speaker

Comment: + operator have special meaning to it. It is a concatenation operator when one of the operand is string. It converts the other to string by invoking toString method if it is object. If it is primitive type, it calls toString method of corresponding Wrapper class. The coercion you are talking about is during assignment or adding it to a collection etc.

Comment: @nits.kk This doesn't have anything to do with autoboxing; this syntax worked before it was introduced.

Comment: oh i am sorry i will remove the comment, thanks for the info, i better refer before putting comment

Answer (score 0):

The place to go is always the Java Language Specification. In this case, we're talking about [15.18.1, String Concatenation Operator +](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> If only one operand expression is of type `String`, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

In particular, the symbol `+` can mean three different things depending on context: unary plus, string concatenation, or addition.

Answer (score 0):

> of conflicting types

The implicit conversion to `String` is not conflicting.  The [JLS, Section 5.1.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11), defines this conversion in a non-conflicting manner.

Basically, any primitive types converted to a wrapper object type, then `toString()` is called on the reference type.  This method is defined on `Object` and thus guaranteed to exist on all reference types.

While this conversion is "automatic", it is not between *conflicting* types, because there is an easily understood, meaningful rule describing the conversion that will always succeed (unless creating an object from the primitive value generates an `OutOfMemoryError`).

This is in contrast to a conflicting conversion called *narrowing primitive conversion*, e.g. `int` to `byte`.  This may lose information, so it does not occur implicitly.  It is legal code only with an explicit cast, e.g. `byte b = (byte) myInt`.

Comment: primitive type auto converting to wrapper class object = autoboxing, but this worked before autoboxing was introduced to java as mentioned in comment by chrylis

Answer (score 0):

In java the automatic type conversion or widening from one data type to another
takes place because the two data types are compatible and the destination type is larger
than the source type. Therefore when a java compiler converts data from one type to
another automatically no information is lost at all because the memory for destination type
is always larger than the source type .However in case of incompatible types the java
compiler checks for type compatibility, if the two types are not compatible than the
automatic type conversion will not take place. If it does it will result in loss of information
automatically. Hence java prevents automatic type between incompatible or conflicting data
types.
In order to convert data between incompatible types java has narrowing conversions. In
narrowing conversions, the two data types may or may not be compatible and the
destination may or may not be larger than the source. In narrowing user explicitly narrows
the data so that it fits the target type. Narrowing may result in loss of information for
example when converting a double to an integer type all information after the decimal point is lost.
Example in java:

```
import java.util.*;
class byteb
{
public static void main(String args [])
{
    double a=30.45;
    int b;
    //b=a;
    b=(int)a;
    System.out.println("b="+a +"and"+ "a="+b);
}
}
```